# Expressjs Routing

Tags: node.js, express

I have these main routes

```
// redirect routes
app.get("router").get("/songs/all", function(req, res){
    res.redirect("/#/songs/all");
});
// API Routes
app.get("router").use("/api/songs", require("./songsController.js")(app));
```

songsController.js looks like this

```
module.exports = function(app){
    app.get("router").get("/all", function(req, res){
        var page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;
        var limit = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 12;
        var offset = (page - 1) * limit;
        models.Song.findAll({
            limit: limit,
            offset: offset
        }).then(function(songs){
            res.json(songs);
        }).catch(function(errors){
            res.send(errors);
        });
    });
    return app.get("router");
};
```

Now the problem is that when i open `/songs/all` url in postman i get the response from `/api/songs/all` url

Comment: What does `app.get("router")` do and why are you using it?

Comment: I saved the router instance in the main app.js file for later use
app.set("router", express.Router())

Comment: Why don't you at least just get it once in each module into a variable rather that getting it everytime you need it?

Comment: Hi Thanks that fixed the problem. Though i would like to know that is this a good practice to do var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();